# Hiding terminal/console on shutdown

Tags: python, shutdown

Is there a way to hide the terminal/console on shutting down the Pi? I've got a python script running that calls Shutdown as a subprocess:

```
# shutdown
subprocess.call("shutdown -h now", shell=True,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

However the shutdown process seems to send the command to the console so it's viewable just before it shuts down can i just add something like /dev/tty1 or /dev/null

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to disable the video output with `tvservice -o` or `vcgencmd display_power 0` just before you run `shutdown`.